# Display message if foreach comes back as empty

Tags: php, wordpress

So I can't seem to figure out this logic, so I'm reaching out to see if someone might be able to help me.

So I have the following `foreach`:

```
echo "Page: " . $page_placement . "/" . $total_pages . "\n\n";
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $current_post_id = post_exists(
        $post->title->rendered,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
    );
    if ($current_post_id === 0) {
        $my_post = [
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'pending',
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($post->title->rendered),
            'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($post->content->rendered),
            'post_excerpt'  => wp_strip_all_tags($post->excerpt->rendered),
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_date'     => $post->date,
        ];

        // Insert post.
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'Global', 'category');
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'Global', 'post_tag');
        echo "ID: " . $post->id . " - Title: " . $post->title->rendered . " has been imported.\n";
    }
}
```

It grabs 50 `$posts` and then loops through and calls `post_exists()` to check the title of the post, and if it doesn't exist, it will import the post otherwise it will skip it.

---

How can I display an echo message if all 50 of the posts aren't imported?

I can't call `if (!$current_post_id) {` inside the foreach, as it will display the message 50 times and I tried to play an variable outside the `foreach` and then call `$my_post[] = [ .... ]` but then the `wp_import_post` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a variable (e.g. $imported, initial value=0) to check the counts. If imported, increment it .

So at last if the variable is still 0, call the echo statement

Hence:

```
<?php
echo "Page: " . $page_placement . "/" . $total_pages . "\n\n";

$imported=0;

foreach ($posts as $post) {


    $current_post_id = post_exists(
        $post->title->rendered,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
    );
    if ($current_post_id === 0) {
        $my_post = [
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'pending',
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($post->title->rendered),
            'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($post->content->rendered),
            'post_excerpt'  => wp_strip_all_tags($post->excerpt->rendered),
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_date'     => $post->date,
        ];

        // Insert post.
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'Global', 'category');
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'Global', 'post_tag');
        echo "ID: " . $post->id . " - Title: " . $post->title->rendered . " has been imported.\n";
        $imported++;
    }

}

if ($imported==0){
echo "No record imported";
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks @Ken, I can't approve the answer for a few minutes, so I'll wait for that.

Comment: Is there a way to handle the `Variable '$imported' is probably undefined` error for the if statement outside the foreach?

Comment: I have slightly amended my answer -- please try my updated answer

Comment: It's perfected, thanks again!

Comment: Good. Have a nice day and happy coding !